# How can I get Eclipse/Jetty/GWT2.0 to find org/apache/commons/logging/Log

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, jetty, apache-commons-logging

I followed the example at http://blog.hivedevelopment.co.uk/2009/08/google-web-toolkit-gwt-mvp-example.html and built the example GWT application, but then I wanted to build something else, and I plan on using Google AppEngine. I started a new GWT2.0 + AppEngine project and followed the same setup of adding the same libararies, copied and modified most of my code from the example project. My code compiles, but now every time I try to debug my app, I get this exception and nothing works. This exception repeats two more times every time I start the service. I thought I might be missing org.apache.commons.logging.Log, but when I ctrl+click to that path, its part of gwt-dev.jar in the GWT SDK. What do I need to do to fix this?

> Jan 26, 2010 5:23:13 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
>   WARNING: failed com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@460ab1b4{/,/home/asa/Projects/Java/Groceries/Shopping/war}
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/Log
>     at com.asaayers.server.guice.ServerModule.configureHandlers(ServerModule.java:20)
>     at net.customware.gwt.dispatch.server.guice.ActionHandlerModule.configure(ActionHandlerModule.java:38)
>     at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
>     at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
>     at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
>     at com.google.inject.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:135)
>     at com.google.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:102)
>     at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:92)
>     at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
>     at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
>     at com.asaayers.server.guice.MyGuiceServletConfig.getInjector(MyGuiceServletConfig.java:11)
>     at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener.contextInitialized(GuiceServletContextListener.java:43)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:530)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:135)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1218)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:500)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
>     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
>     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:217)
>     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:188)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:120)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:86)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:377)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:938)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:690)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:251)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:151)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
>     ... 31 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Guice uses [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/). 
The tutorial describes how to put a whole bunch of jars in war/WEB-INF/bin. You'll need to download the zip file from the commons-logging site, open it up and find commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, and put that in war/WEB-INF/lib.

Commons-logging will find that you have log4j in your class path, and automatically use that.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed. The tutorial lists a bunch of other jars that I added, but seems to leave out commons-logging. Do you happen to know why I need that jar now, but I didn't seem to need it in the example project?

Comment: Dhanji says Guice doesn't require commons-logging. It seems the com.asaayers.server.guice.ServerModule class is trying to use it in the configureHandlers() method. Perhaps some configuration option is telling Guice to use commons-logging.

Answer (score 0):

Guice does NOT use commons-logging. Perhaps one of your other libraries uses it. Guice only depends on the core JDK (5.0).